# Уведомление о прочтении письма python

Tags: python, email

Не приходят уведомления о прочтении письма

Укажите пжл, где ошибка в коде

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.utils import make_msgid 

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = "Subject text"
msg['From'] =from
msg['To'] = to
msg['Message-ID'] = make_msgid()
msg['Disposition-Notification-To'] = from
msg.set_content('Test')
s = smtplib.SMTP('emailServer')
s.send_message(msg, rcpt_options=['NOTIFY=SUCCESS,DELAY,FAILURE'])
s.quit()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если делать отправку письма через Microsoft Outlook с указанием атрибута "Уведомление о прочтении" всё проходит нормально. Но вот если я отправляю письмо с этого же хоста через python уведомление о прочтении не приходит

Answer (score 3):

Помогло добавление вот этой строчки

```
msg['X-Confirm-Reading-To'] = from
```

При этом на другом почтовом сервере было достаточно этой строчки

```
msg['Disposition-Notification-To'] = from
```